# Cardview with dividers in it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

I've seen those `CardViews` (I'm not sure they're even `CardViews`) with dividers used in a lot of apps, so I'm guessing there is an easy way to create them.
I wanted to ask how is it exactly done? are those even `CardViews`?

I couldn't find out more about them because I didn't know the name of the `View` exactly, so If someone could direct me to an example with code I'd be grateful.

Image example:
[image]

Comment: I think it's listitems with having background and divider  parameters in list.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use this code this may help

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Conversations" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="game" />
                    ...
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393540/no-shadow-elevation-underneath-second-card-if-there-are-two-card-in-the-layout

Answer (score 13):

The shown screenshot shows a normal CardView with views as divider in-between. 
There is no DividerView or something similar if you searching for something like this. Just use a simple `View` with a height and a background.

I've something similar in a library of mine. I use this to create the divider:

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/stroke"/>
```

---

**card_library.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/libraryname"
            style="@style/CardTitle"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/libraryversion"
            style="@style/CardTitle"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="left|bottom"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/librarycreator"
            style="@style/CardTitle"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/stroke"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            style="@style/CardText"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:maxLines="20">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

It will then look like this:

[image: Divider]

Comment: please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393540/no-shadow-elevation-underneath-second-card-if-there-are-two-card-in-the-layout

Comment: what color are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Set app:cardElevation="0dp" then use a View - see below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/cv"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
app:cardElevation="0dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!-- Insert UI elements -->

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_height="2dp"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```